# Inherit values from a master file in Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

Currently, I need to put

```
location ~ \.php$
{
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

in each and every site that I need  to run PHP files.

Is there a way to just put it in a "master", so that all sites won't have duplicate copies of the same directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes like so:

```
include /etc/nginx/master.conf;
```

for more details see http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include

In other words where you had:

```
server {
  servername a;
  location ~ \.php$ { fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;}

  #rest of server a config
}

server {
  servername b;
  location ~ \.php$ { fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;}

  #rest of server b config
}
```

you'd now have:

```
server {
  servername a;
  include /etc/nginx/php-master.conf;

  #rest of server a config
}

server{
  servername b;
  include /etc/nginx/php-master.conf;

  #rest of server b config
}
```

and a seperate file /etc/ningx/php-master.conf with as content

```
location ~ \.php$ { 
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

It doesn't actually shorten the code in the serverblock much (as the included bit is just 1 line). But it still yields the advantage that you can now change your php settings in 1 place (say you move your fastcgi handler to a different port or ip)

Comment: The thing is, even if I put this code in the master file: `location ~ \.php$
{
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}`
PHP files won't work on individual sites unless I put that same code on their own `server { }` block

Comment: basically behind the scenes nginx will replace the include directive with the contents of the included file before interpreting the result. (updated my answer to illustrate)

Comment: ahh so that's how it works. I guess this is good enough. thanks

Comment: If I include the same location directive within the server block and put a different value, will it merge the master value or will it hold only the values mentioned in the server block?